How to port forward from MacOS to VM Ware to a service with private IP
My host IP - 192.168.0.99 - mac
VM IP - 192.168.0.219 - VMWare Fusion os is ubuntu
Service listens on 10.10.10.100:5000 in VM
VMs network adapter is set to bridge
How do I connect from my host OS to a service in VM?
I tried to portforward on vm:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -d 192.168.0.219 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.100:5000
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.10.10.100 --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE

Also added to /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf
[incomingtcp]
# Use these with care - anyone can enter into your VM through these...
# The format and example are as follows:
#<external port number> = <VM's IP address>:<VM's port number>
#8080 = 172.16.3.128:80
5000 = 192.168.0.219:5000

But connection can not be establsihed.

psql -h 192.168.0.219 -p 5000 -U postgres psql: error: connection to
server at "192.168.0.219", port 5000 failed: Operation timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?


As said in the message: “Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?”. Have you checked this?

@Toto yes I've checked. from VM I can connect to 10.10.10.100:500.
